# Where is the IMAP support in the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, imap, email

One year ago Mitchel Sellers had a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86553/working-with-pop-imap-email-and-net) question...

I would like to access the Google IMAP for sending and receiving email messages within my custom application.

The point is that i would not like to use any third party controls.

Newer versions of the .Net Framework support IMAP? What options do i have?

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers but still the same answer

Comment: @Will There is also the world wide web becides the SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be the [Indy components](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx) for Borland Delphi which have been [ported to C#](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=IndySockets) and .NET.

There is no native support for this, As far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no .NET framework support for IMAP. You'll need to use some 3rd party component.

Try [Mail.dll email component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail), it's very affordable and easy to use:

```
using(Imap imap = new Imap())
{
    imap.Connect("imapServer");
    imap.Login("user", "password");

    imap.SelectInbox();
    List<long> uids = imap.SearchFlag(Flag.Unseen);
    foreach (long uid in uids)
    {
        string eml = imap.GetMessageByUID(uid);
        IMail message = new MailBuilder()
            .CreateFromEml(eml);

        Console.WriteLine(message.Subject);
        Console.WriteLine(message.TextDataString);
    }
    imap.Close(true);
}
```

You can download it here: [http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail).

Comment: I have made the switch to Ubuntu for future development. Is there any way to get this library to work with C# Mono on Linux or to work with the Vala programming language?

Answer (score -2):

There is no IMAP support in current versions of .NET and I have not heard about any plans to add such support to the framework. You have to try one of third party components.

You may check our [Rebex Secure Mail](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/).

Following code shows how to download messages from the `Inbox` folder:

```
// create client, connect and log in 
Imap client = new Imap();
client.Connect("imap.example.org");
client.Login("username", "password");

// select folder 
client.SelectFolder("Inbox");

// get message list 
ImapMessageCollection list = client.GetMessageList(ImapListFields.Fast);

if (list.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There are no messages in the mailbox.");
}
else 
{
    // download the first message 
    MailMessage message = client.GetMailMessage(list[0].SequenceNumber);
    ...
}
```

Trial can be downloaded from [www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/download.aspx)

You may also enjoy [Rebex Q&A forum](http://forum.rebex.net) which runs on similar engine as this site.