# Check for unread emails

Tags: c#, email, imap

I'm looking for a way to check the number of unread emails on an email account.
Any tips?

EDIT: As described in the tags, for C#. As I learned IMAP is the way to go and I confirmed all email accounts I'm going to use have IMAP activated :)

Comment: You need to include more information.  You've tagged this as C# so we can assume that is the programming language in question, but you need to specify mail protocol (POP, IMAP, Exchange, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**POP**

[You can use OpenPOP.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/) to  read emails using POP protocol. The problem with POP is that it does not hold details whether it was unread or not. So I think this will not be of much use to you. You have have your own way of downloading and tagging emails as read or unread.

**IMAP**

[This question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers) has some links for examples using IMAP. IMAP has details about mail status(read/unread).

Please explain more about your requirement.

Comment: I edited my question. I'll check out the IMAP link and check this as answered if it's the way to go. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is get the number of unread messages in an IMAP folder, you can use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) to do this:

```
using MailKit;
using MailKit.Search;
using MailKit.Net.Imap;
```

...

```
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
    // Note: depending on your server, you might need to connect
    // on port 993 using SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect
    client.Connect ("imap.server.com", 143, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

    // Note: use your real username/password here...
    client.Authenticate ("username", "password");

    // open the Inbox folder...
    client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    // search the folder for new messages (aka recently
    // delivered messages that have not been read yet)
    var uids = client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.New);

    Console.WriteLine ("You have {0} new message(s).", uids.Count);

    // ...but maybe you mean unread messages? if so, use this query
    uids = client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.NotSeen);

    Console.WriteLine ("You have {0} unread message(s).", uids.Count);

    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample of code with LumiSoft IMAP library:

```
using LumiSoft.Net.IMAP;
using LumiSoft.Net.IMAP.Client;
using LumiSoft.Net;
```

...

```
using (IMAP_Client client = new IMAP_Client())
{
    client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
    client.Login("your.username@gmail.com", "your_cool_password");
    client.SelectFolder("INBOX");

    IMAP_SequenceSet sequence = new IMAP_SequenceSet();
    //sequence.Parse("*:1"); // from first to last

    IMAP_Client_FetchHandler fetchHandler = new IMAP_Client_FetchHandler();

    fetchHandler.NextMessage += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("next message");
    });

    fetchHandler.Envelope += new EventHandler<EventArgs<IMAP_Envelope>>(delegate(object s, EventArgs<IMAP_Envelope> e){
        IMAP_Envelope envelope = e.Value;
        if (envelope.From != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(envelope.Subject))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(envelope.Subject);
        }

    });

    // the best way to find unread emails is to perform server search

    int[] unseen_ids = client.Search(false, "UTF-8", "unseen");
    Console.WriteLine("unseen count: " + unseen_ids.Count().ToString());

    // now we need to initiate our sequence of messages to be fetched
    sequence.Parse(string.Join(",", unseen_ids));

    // fetch messages now
    client.Fetch(false, sequence, new IMAP_Fetch_DataItem[] { new IMAP_Fetch_DataItem_Envelope() }, fetchHandler);

    // uncomment this line to mark messages as read
    // client.StoreMessageFlags(false, sequence, IMAP_Flags_SetType.Add, IMAP_MessageFlags.Seen);
}
```

Bit complicated, but works fine. Limisoft library is not perfect, so be sure you test it well.