# How read hotmail emails using with c#

Tags: c#, dll, hotmail

Check these out :

**1-** 
[Easiest way to read hotmail emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715971/easiest-way-to-read-hotmail-emails)
but it seems [OpenPop.NET](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/) has been deprecated and does not work any more!
i tried "**pop3.live.com**" with "**995**" port and both **ssl** [true | false] and full email address as username and always got an error.
i tried *OpenPopTest* in their solution and with **ssl** **true** i got the error below :

[image: <code>The server did not accept the user credentials!</code>]

and with **ssl** **false** i got the error below :

[image]

**2-** [Hotmail-using-C-A-HTTPMail-client-under-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3857/Hotmail-using-C-A-HTTPMail-client-under-NET)
but http://services.msn.com/svcs/hotmail/httpmail.asp. does not exist any more!

would be really appreciate to give me a solution about that.

**EDIT :**
here is the *OpenPopTest* window in http://hpop.sourceforge.net/'s solution and i did n't change any thing in code-behind.

[image]

Comment: Might help if you show us the error you get with trying to use pop3.live.com 995 with ssl. Might be as simple as you aren't using full email address. But without the error and example code you are using... Not much we can help with.

Comment: You are using your full email address when connecting right? Also, post your code related to the connection (obviously comment out if you have hardcoded user/pass information)

Comment: @JClaspill hi, thanks for the comment(s). please check my question again. i edit it.

Comment: Considering Hotmail has been superseded by Outlook.com, perhaps this link will help: [Connect to Outlook.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/dn440163.aspx)

Comment: You should probably ask Microsoft... It looks like there's an entire [Outlook.com API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535) out there.

Comment: thanks, working on it, i found this -> http://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth2-outlook-com-imap-web-applications

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set POP setting to True in Your hotmail account
follow  Settings -> Accounts -> POP and IMAP , set True

Pop3 URL is also changed so please use  ***pop-mail.outlook.com*** instead of pop3.live.com.

for further details please reffer this URL 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/livemail-email/wlm-2012-hotmail-error-0x800ccc92/4c37b2b7-c8ce-4ac6-9cd5-9d13368ff167?auth=1