# IMAP getting Response issue

Tags: imap

Iam working on IMAP, reading mail content I got twice or third times of same mails content.

I had check out different different scenario so I comes to know Response() was gives me repeatitive
content.

I am passing Command like this.

```
                byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(("$ UID FETCH " + index + " (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM DATE)])" + "\r\n").ToCharArray());
        _imapNs.Write(commandBytes, 0, commandBytes.Length);
        _imapNs.Flush();
        string strMsg = Response();
```

my member of Stream and TcpClient is.

```
private TcpClient _imapClient;
private Stream _imapNs;
```

and my Response method is here.

```
private string Response()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[_imapClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
    int ret = _imapNs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
}
```

once I had check this complete cycle then I comes to knows the Response() method gives me repeatitive content so is there any solution for that.....

Thanks...!!

Comment: Which language are you using? C#?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the Solution, because I want to do all the thing inside the loop and I am doing all the thins outside the loop Thanks..!!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way your code will work.

You have assumed that the server response is smaller than _imapClient.ReceiveBufferSize. Why?

Server response may be 50 MB long. There is no way you'll be able to read it with the single call to Stream.Read method.

Comment: Sorry to say but it's working some time's it give me repeatitive content. _imapClient.ReceiveBufferSize is the Fix size,I dont Know whether that would be the problem or not.

Comment: Well if it's working sometimes it is  **NOT ** working. What happens if the response is 2025 bytes long and your buffer size (_imapClient.ReceiveBufferSize) is e.g. 1024? You need to use a loop over Read method.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use one of the many libraries available for C# (I'm assuming that's what you're using due to the syntax of your example - you didn't specify).

Take a look at the existing StackOverflow questions.

[Accessing IMAP in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670183/accessing-imap-in-c)

[Using C# .NET librarires to check for IMAP messages from GMail servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers)

Comment: ok, but our requirement is not match for this so we need to customize the IMAP Client.