# Import emails to my webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am creating an ASP.NET/C# Web Apllication.

I want to import my emails (from Gmail, or hotmail or others,... doesn't matter)

and show the title and the message of each email on my webpage.

Is there a way to do this? maybe an API to use?

Any helps or tips are greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much

Comment: This is something you could have Googled yourself. - http://www.google.com/search?q=Gmail+API - And if you're asking how to implement that on your ASP page, that question is too broad. Give it a try yourself and post here if you have a *specific* question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [InterIMAP](http://interimap.codeplex.com/)

> > InterIMAP is an IMAP client library written in C# targeting the .NET 2.0 framework

Here is a link to the [documentation](http://interimap.codeplex.com/documentation)

**Edit**

Here is a link to a similar question which has a number of answers: [using c# .net librarires to check for IMAP messages from gmail servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers)