# Confirm that mail successfully arrived

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail, sendmail

i am used gmail to send mails from my asp.net page , but i want a method to Confirm ( make sure ) that the message successfully  arrived to the recipients ( i add some recipients to BCC )

anybody can help me ??

Comment: This is the first google result searching "c# mail receipt" does it help ? http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Requesting-deliveryread-receipt-from-C-using-MailMessage-class.aspx

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways

- request a read receipt
- embed image to mail body

but as I know google doesn't support them. anyway search about those two ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not do this from your "send code" directly. I guess you need to use a some POP3 or IMAP api to see if there are a new email was recieved by recipient.

For example, you can only test if SMTP-server has accepted o rejected you message (spam-reason, auth error), but your cannot check if email was recieved by opponent

Or you maybe can use a "autoanswer" feature of you email client

Comment: thnx , can u give me example !!?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the some POP3 (protocol) library to check the recipient has received your email. POP3 is what you can use for retrieving mail, but it does not have support for PUSH either (so you would have to poll for mail).

The [IMAP4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) IDLE extension is what most refer to as PUSH mail - so you will need to find a library for C# that supports IMAP4 IDLE.

Check this link Using [C# .Net Libraries to Check for Imap Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-sharp-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers)
and also check this [Accessing IMAP in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-sharp-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers)

Keep in mind that your mail server also needs to have IMAP4 and IMAP4 IDLE enabled. Some mail servers don't support it, and will have to use POP3 polling.

Answer (score 0):

With standard RFC822 email there's really no way to confirm receipt.  To send a message, the mail client will talk to an SMTP server.  The server may reject gross problems (ex. malformed email addresses).  The server will attempt to forward the message to the destinations but somewhere along the way the message could fall on the floor.  And of course the message could wind up in the destination mailbox but perhaps no one will read it.

Typically if delivery fails you'll eventually get a bounce message but this won't occur at the same time mail is delivered.