# .NET how to retrieve list of emails from Gmail server with out third party

Tags: imap, email, .net-4.5

I want to retrieve all my Gmail mails and show them in .NET 4.5 WPF application. i don't want to pay for any third party dll. Is there any thing build-in available in .NET 4.5 or later versions? Note: i am not worried about sending mail. All my requirement is to show all [read/Unread/New] mail in my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using c# .net librarires to check for IMAP messages from gmail servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-sharp-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no .NET framework support for the IMAP or POP3 protocols you would use to do this. You would need to use a 3rd party DLL - there are free ones available. Or implement the protocol yourself using C# - I'm not going to attempt to provide sample code for that, though.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-sharp-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers) which discusses some of the components available, as well as having an answer which specifically states that there is no .NET framework support.