# Reading Emails from Gmail C# - IMAP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gmail, imap

I'm trying to read emails from specific Gmail account. I have found something here(Stackoverflow) but I can't manage reading the emails.

this is what I'm using:

```
 public static void logingmail()
    {
        // Connect to the IMAP server. The 'true' parameter specifies to use SSL
        // which is important (for Gmail at least)
        ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", "Any@gmail.com", "4521945219",AuthMethods.Login, 993, true);
        // Select a mailbox. Case-insensitive
        ic.SelectMailbox("Inbox");
       string countmessages = ic.GetMessageCount().ToString();
        // Get the first *11* messages. 0 is the first message;
        // and it also includes the 10th message, which is really the eleventh ;)
        // MailMessage represents, well, a message in your mailbox
        MailMessage[] mm = ic.GetMessages(0, 10);
        foreach (MailMessage m in mm)
        {

            var subject = m.Subject.ToString();
        }
        // Probably wiser to use a using statement
        ic.Dispose();

    }
```

The problem I'm experiencsing probably happening when I'm first creating the new ImapCliient class. for some reason it's opening a browse path to choose a file(?).
I'll be happy for some assistance.
Thanks

Comment: This file browser dialog appearing is strange. Have you tryed to debug this  method? on what line this dialog appears? And wrap your method in try-catch block, maybe there is an unhandled exception is thrown

Comment: Strange indeed. It happens on the first line. ImapClient ic= new ImapClient(......); I have tried debugging it. But I will add try and catch wrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using c# .net librarires to check for IMAP messages from gmail servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-sharp-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the solution of the second post of the topic were you have found something, [S22.Imap](https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap).
([Here](http://smiley22.github.com/Downloads/S22.Imap.zip) you can find a compiled version).

After download, you can read the documentation. It is simple and readable.

Actually, I use this library and that works well !

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: @Yaniv Eliav If you have any questions, you can find the documention [here](http://smiley22.github.io/S22.Imap/Documentation/).

Comment: I'm using the S22 library. but when using the code, it seems like "<Mailmessages>" part is not recognized.
 IEnumerable<Mailmessages>

Comment: The type is "MailMessage" and not "MailMessages". Test with capital letters at "Mail" and "Message" without "s".